# What is reflexivity in temporal logic?

Tags: logic, time, modal-logic

According to Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, reflexivity can be defined by :

> ∀x(x ≺ x)

Where **≺** means "Precedes" : **`For all x, x precedes x`**

But what does it mean for an instant in time x to precede itself? I do not get this point?

**The Question : What does reflexivity mean?**

**Reference**

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/

Comment: Does it mean recurrent time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is just a definition**

If the definition is useful really depends on what you want to model. 
The author of the SEP article does not know what you want to do, so he includes a reasonable amount of hopefully useful definitions.

Usually, it doesn't make sense to be reflexive, the article itself says so.

> There are some basic properties which can naturally be imposed on instant-based flows of time. It is usually required to be a strict partial ordering, that is, an **irreflexive** and transitive relation

<sub>From [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/#InsBasModFloTim), my emphasis.</sub>

But as an example, if you want to describe a repeating process, circular time is a natural way to do so. Since transitivitiy  still holds, every point precedes itself. Or think of a process that might branch, and possibly has loops. Then points that "precede themselve" are exactly those which sit in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much,  I thought there is another way to look at this definitions other than circular (recurrent) time or possible loops. Because another string of thinking may suggest that even if an instant x repeats in time, every instance of the same instant is not identical to another one, even if the same instant repeats itself, that's why I thought that maybe I misunderstood the point, after all it is all definitions, thanks